# Efficient way to estimate the order p for autoregressive model AR(p)?

Tags: time-series, model-selection, autoregressive

I am writing an algorithms to build AR model to estimate stock price in the future. However, I have 88 stocks to look at and wonder whether there is any efficient way to estimate the order p for all of the 88 different stocks. Normally, I would like at the cutoff point at pacf curve, but it is simply too inefficient to do so for 88 of them.

Comment: There are numerous versions of this question already; no wonder, everyone working with ARIMA has to deal with lag order selection. Check out the existing posts and the popular algorithms such as `auto.arima`, then decide which one you like best.

Answer (score 0):

I would first consider whether it is possible to spot some kind of pattern in those PACF. It may give you a general rule to establish a maximum order.

Now calculating the PACFs will not be so inefficient, as you can do it only for a given set of lags that are often relevant.